# How can I find the status of child orders in BracketOrders in InteractiveBroker TWS API?

Tags: interactive-brokers, tws

I am trying to place an order based on [this link](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/bracket_order.html). Is there any way to find out the status of child orders e.g. after 10 minutes? For example check to see if StopLoss order is done or not.

It seems using `reqAllOpenOrders`, `reqCompletedOrders`, or `reqOpenOrders` doesn't work for this purpose.

Is there any idea, how we can do that?